# Convert 2D numpy array to Tensorflow Dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a numpy array of the shape (n, 12) representing the input datapoints of my data, of floating point formal, and a numpy array of shape (n,) containing the labels of the datapoints (integer).

However, I can't work out how to convert it into a tensorflow dataset - the guide method throws an error:

Offending line of code is `dataset= tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))` giving an error `TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got Decimal('0.4367')`

Thanks

Comment: Edit your post to include your code and the errors

Comment: Added the code and the error

Comment: It seems like either `features` or `labels` is of unexpected type. Are you reading them from a text file? Did you convert from string to a numeric format before trying to build the dataset?

Comment: It's processed externally such that features is all decimal values and labels is entirely integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that one of your input arrays contains elements of type [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html). TensorFlow does not support this type natively, so you will have to convert the array to either `np.float32` or `np.float64`.

For example, assuming `features` is the array containing `Decimal` values, you could convert it as follows:

```
import numpy as np
features = np.array([decimal.Decimal(1.0), decimal.Decimal(2.0), decimal.Decimal(3.0)])

print(features)  # ==> "[Decimal('1') Decimal('2') Decimal('3')]"
print(features.dtype)  # ==> "object"

features = features.astype(np.float32)

print(features)  # ==> "[1. 2. 3. 4.]"
print(features.dtype)  # ==> "float32"
```